# Opening .py files in PyCharm Editor

Tags: python, pycharm

Currently, I have PyCharm recognizing the .py extension and all .py files have the PyCharm icon. However, when I double click on a .py file, the project opens up (if it's in a project) and on the left hand side I can see everything in my project folder, but the center of PyCharm is telling me "No files are open." I can open, write, and run scratch files though.

How do I get the python script in the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you press ALT-1 you will see on the left, files of your current open project. If you click on file with .py and it does not open in the Editor window, it may mean your default layout got somehow changed. Press Shift-F12 to restore to default layout, and click on a .py file again.
Other thing to try is to delete .idea folder in the project directory and restart Pycharm.

Comment: Just had to delete the .PyCharm40 folder and restart PyCharm.